# Why doesn't my sqlite3 in-memory table exist after running a CREATE query?

Tags: python, sqlite, twisted

I'm trying to create an in-memory sqlite3 database using Twisted's `twisted.enterprise.adbapi.ConnectionPool` class.  My test-case is as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.enterprise.adbapi import ConnectionPool

sql_init = (
    "CREATE TABLE ajxp_index ( node_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT );",
    "INSERT INTO ajxp_index (node_id) VALUES (9001);",
)


@task.react
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor):
    cp = ConnectionPool("sqlite3", ":memory:", check_same_thread=False)
    for sql in sql_init:
        print(sql)
        yield cp.runQuery(sql)
```

Running the above script produces the following error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: ajxp_index`

Where things get strange is if we replace `:memory:` with a path to a file on persistent storage, e.g.:  `/tmp/foo.sqlite`.  Under *this* condition, the script executes as expected.

Further, running the same SQL queries using the `sqlite3` module in the standard library runs as expected:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
for sql in sql_init:  # same commands as in above example
    conn.execute(sql)
```

What gives?  Is this a bug in Twisted, or am I doing something wrong?

## EDIT:

As per notorious.no's suggestion, I've updated my example to use `cp.runInteraction`, but the result remains the same:

```
@task.react
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor):
    cp = ConnectionPool("sqlite3", ":memory:", check_same_thread=False)
    for sql in sql_init:
        print(sql)
        yield cp.runInteraction(lambda cursor: cursor.execute(sql))
```

## EDIT 2

Okay, this seems to work:

```
def _interact(cursor, script):
    cursor.executescript(script)


@task.react
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor):
    cp = ConnectionPool("sqlite3", ":memory:", check_same_thread=False)
    yield cp.runInteraction(_interact, "\n".join(sql_init))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you're doing `cp.runQuery`, instead it should be `runInteraction`.

```
cp.runInteraction(lambda cursor, stmt: cursor.execute(stmt))
```

I wrote a post that might be helpful https://notoriousno.blogspot.com/2016/08/twisted-klein-database-usage.html?m=1